# How can I define the order of start and stop of Linux services?

Tags: services

Example, when I turn on my server,  I want to start mysql first then the NTP service.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for Upstart. Upstart stanza `start on` can establish the order services are started.

In the example you proposed, NTP doesn't have an upstart script so you should create it and define the start stanza:

```
start on started mysql
```

Of course, mysql should have a upstart job too. There are pretty cool things, for example if you need to start a job when a internet connection get up:

```
start on net-device-up IFACE!=lo
```

This start the job when any network device, besides lo, is up.

References:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#event
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#really-understanding-start-on-and-stop-on (here is the example about mysql)